# Having multiple firestore listener?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Currently, I am making the **post system** just like Facebook **where each post has a like-count & comment-count** which has to be updated in **real-time**.

So what is the **best practice** for setting up the listener? **between**

1.Set up the listener on the collection itself and then (then make use of the snapshot-data that returned)

2.Set up a listener on each post and remove the listener later at some point when un-needed -> (I am planning to set-up the listener only the post that visible to the screen if it is scrolled up it will then automatically unregister the listener)

3. any other way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just marked it as the accepted answer. Yes, It does make sense. sorry for the very late I just have successfully recovered my account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no singular best practice. It all depends on how much data you're likely to show to your users.

You'll find that approach 2 is a lot more difficult to implement, especially since you seem interesting in using listeners. If the underlying data can be changed in many ways, this is at times really hard to deal with. But given your use-case it *may* be feasible, so [YMMV](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ymmv).

If you choose to use option 1, definitely [limit the number of documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) you return at a maximum.